# no entry point found in windows dll while using regsvr32

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, dll

I'm trying to create a DLL in Visual C++ express 2008. My DLL proyect compiles fine and the *.dll is created. However, when I try to register it with regsvr32 I get the following error message:

"The name.dll module was loaded, but the entry ponint was not found, DllUnregisterServer" (the message goes something like that, I'm translating it from my spanish version of Windows).

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit O.S. But I think the *.dll is created in 32 bit because of my version of Visual C++ Express...

Her is the code:

DLL.h

```
#ifndef DLLHEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define DLLHEADER_H_INCLUDED

#ifdef DLL_EXPORTS
 #define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
 #define DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C"
{
 struct DLL_API Datos
 {
  char cad1[100];
  char cad2[100];
  char cad3[100];
 };

 DLL_API void __stdcall funcion(char*);
 DLL_API void __stdcall saludo(void);
}

#endif
```

DLL.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DLL.h"

void __stdcall funcion(char* ptr)
{
 Datos* d = (Datos*)ptr;

 std::cout<<"DESDE LA DLL : \n";
 std::cout<<"Cadena1 : "<<d->cad1<<'\n';
 std::cout<<"Cadena1 : "<<d->cad2<<'\n';
 std::cout<<"Cadena1 : "<<d->cad3<<'\n';
}

void _stdcall saludo(void)
{
 std::cout<<"Hola desde DLL.\n";
}
```

I created the proyect following a MSDN tutorial and the template also adds this file:

dllmain.cpp

```
// dllmain.cpp : Define el 'entry point' para la aplicación DLL.
#include "stdafx.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
 switch (ul_reason_for_call)
 {
  case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH :
  case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH  :
  case DLL_THREAD_DETACH  :
  case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH :
                           break;
 }

 return TRUE;
}
```

As fas as I understand, everything is fine, but apparently I can't register the *.dll.

Is something missing?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

regsvr32 is only used with ActiveX/COM servers.  Your DLL is not a COM server, so there is no point in calling regsvr32 for your DLL in the first place, as there is nothing to register/unregister.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read in the msdn online documetation the following "The Regsvr32 Tool (regsvr32.exe) is used to register or un–register a COM DLL." So, this kind of, lets say, "C/C++ DLL" is different from a COM one?

Comment: COM is not a language, it is framework.  It stands for "Component Object Model" (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680573.aspx).  A plain ordinary C/C++ DLL like you have written is not a COM DLL, however you can write COM DLLs in plain C/C++ using the ATL framework, which you are not using.  Why are you trying to register your DLL in the first place?  For what purpose?

Comment: Well, what happen is that this is just a test dll which is supposed to be used by a Progress 4GL aplication, and the Progress developers told me that the dll needed to be registered so they can use it. So I was testing this part as well.

Comment: What exactly did they tell you to do?  Did they tell you to create a plain flat ordinary DLL, or did they tell you to create a COM DLL?  It makes a *BIG* difference in how you code it.  I suspect the latter is actually the case, in which case you will need to start over from scratch.  Have Visual Studio create an ATL project with its Application Type set to DLL, then define a COM object in the project's Type Library, implement the associated class as needed, and finally register the compiled DLL with regsvr32.